# Add SSIS packages to Microsoft Visual Source Safe

Tags: ssis, visual-sourcesafe

I have bunch of SSIS packages. Now we have 3 developers who will be working on it. These packages need to be added to the VSS. What is the best way to add packages to Visual Source Safe ?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend adding your packages to (a) project(s) on Visual Studio, grouping them however makes sense. You can then add the entire project to Source Safe, and manage the packages/projects as you would any other project.